# continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, differentiable on $\mathbb{R}_0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)<\infty$. Is $f$ differentiable in $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have found a proof but I'd like to see if it's correct.

> Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}_0$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ exists and is finite. Then $f$ is differentiable in $0$ as well.

$\textbf{Proof}:$ Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,\varepsilon]$. The function is also differentiable on $(0,\varepsilon)$. Hence by the mean value theorem there is a $\xi\in(0,\varepsilon)$ such that $$f'(\xi) = \dfrac{f(\varepsilon)-f(0)}{\varepsilon-0}.$$
Now, notice that $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}f'(\xi)=\lim_{\xi \to 0}f'(\xi) < \infty$$
and hence $$\lim_{\xi \to 0}f'(\xi) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\dfrac{f(\varepsilon)-f(0)}{\varepsilon-0}<\infty.$$
So $f$ is differentiable in 0.

Comment: The denominator should be $\varepsilon-0$.

Comment: Is that IVT or lagrange's MVT?

Comment: @Shamim, yes it's Lagrange, sorry I made the proof in another language than English and accidentally mixed the two theorem names up.

Comment: Thats fine :)..